# How to sound-proof a room with minimal budget

Tags: sound-proofing

In my house, I have a room upstairs in which I frequently do videocalls. The problem is that when I talk my family can hear everything downstairs, which is very annoying for them. So I would like to try to make it so my voice isn't hearable outside the room.
This room has a wooden floor, through which I think the sound goes through the most, so maybe carpets? It also has wooden door.
What measures can I take to improve the situation with minimal budget?

EDIT: I wouldn't like to build a structure around me, but to improve the room I'm already in

Comment: Use a headset with a microphone, speak quietly and turn the gain up? ;-)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I actually use a headset with a mic but my family is either too sensitive or the room too bad isolating sound

Answer (score 2):

I would start with an area rug to cover most of the floor.

Hanging tapestries on the walls and door can add to the decor and help deaden the sound.

Do you have access to the underside of the floor from below? This would be the spot to add insulation.

The problem with lower frequencies (male voices) is they resonate the building itself and are more difficult to block.

Good luck!